# array size is reset to 0 at the end of this recursive function

Tags: ruby

My goal is to return an array `bin` which contains the combination of elements of an array that will add up to certain max value.

I can't figure out why `bin` is reset to empty. Please help me figure this out.

```
def session_bin(arr, max) 
  array = arr.sort
  bin = []
  bin_value = max
  start = 0
  sum = array[start]
  p array
  array.each_with_index do |l,i|
    p "----before SUM-----#{sum}"

    if sum <= bin_value 
      bin << l
    end   

    if i < array.size-1
      i += 1
    end

    sum  +=  array[i]

    p "bin = #{bin}" 

    while sum > bin_value and i < array.size  do
      sum  -=  array[i]
    end

    return bin if bin.inject(:+) == bin_value

    break if bin.inject(:+) == bin_value
    p "----after SUM-----#{sum}"
  end

  p "---------------------------------------"

  array.delete_at(start)

  p "SUM--------#{sum}"

  if sum < bin_value
    bin.clear
    sum = 0
    session_bin(array, max)
  end 

  p "size = #{bin.size}"
  p bin if !bin.empty?
end


my_instance.session_bin([5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60], 180)
```

Here's the output i see (partial)

```
"----before SUM-----30" 
"bin = [30]"
"----after SUM-----60"
"----before SUM-----60"
"bin = [30, 30]"
"----after SUM-----90"
"----before SUM-----90"
"bin = [30, 30, 30]"
"----after SUM-----120"
"----before SUM-----120"
"bin = [30, 30, 30, 30]"
"----after SUM-----150"
"----before SUM-----150"
"bin = [30, 30, 30, 30, 30]"
"----after SUM-----180"
"----before SUM-----180"
"bin = [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]"
"size = 0"
```

Comment: Just a note.  You don't need the `then` in your `if` branching

Comment: modified the code. Thank you

Comment: cool man :)  Can you provide an example of what you expect to get for a result given some input array?  I find this is usually the best way to convey what I'm trying to do - and rspec is really convenient to help me understand and convey exactly what I'm trying to do ( not saying to include rspec here, but on your end, it may help in development ).

Comment: Why wouldn't it be empty?  You call `bin.clear` most of the time just before the print.  By the way, this is not a good way to solve this problem.  Google for "subset sum problem" for full explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gene. I'm new to ruby that's why my code is not so elegant and I'm not aware of any debugging tools like eclipse ide. I had RubyMine which seems like a good tool but its not free. Free version license got expired hence this obfuscation in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not recursive but...

```
def session_bin(arr, max)
  1.upto(arr.size).map { |i| arr.combination(i).to_a }.flatten(1).select { |a| a.inject(:+) == max }.uniq
end

p session_bin [5, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60], 180

#> [[60, 60, 60], [30, 30, 60, 60], [30, 45, 45, 60], [45, 45, 45, 45], [30, 30, 30, 30, 60], [30, 30, 30, 45, 45], [30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30]]
```

Comment: Wow! Thats amazing one line code. Thanks a TON @seph. You are awesome

Comment: Welcome. It's the Ruby way :>

Comment: a related question.
I'd like return arrays that match whose sum is > 180 and < 240
Could you please show the syntax for this condition in your code?
Thanks again!

Comment: @Sudhakar: just add a min parameter to session_bin and use between? instead of == in the select block

Comment: ah! alright. I was not aware of 'between'. Thank you again. Appreciate it